# Info button push to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have an info button in the top left of my iPhone App, i had to add this using code as the bar button item doesn't support an info button, code below...

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

i want this button to push to a UIViewController called AboutViewController, what do i need to do to this code to make that work, been trying for ages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a selector to the button to be performed on the control event you specify.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(iClickedMyButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

From there, just push how you normally would.

```
- (void)iClickedMyButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    AboutViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AboutVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can't work out where to put 'AboutViewController' to make it work

Comment: @CarlRydings Where are you configuring `AboutViewController`? Code/storyboard/xib?

Comment: main.storyboard (Custom class: AboutViewController) and AboutViewController.h and .m as Objective-C classes

Comment: @CarlRydings See my edited code, you'll have to assign the view controller a storyboard ID in Interface Builder, but this should be enough for you to see what to do.

Comment: Thanks, I have done all that. However, XCode is giving me this error on the second section of code: Use of undeclared identifier 'controller' and Use of undeclared identifier 'AboutViewController'

Comment: @CarlRydings Have you imported AboutViewController's header into this implementation file? And you need to make sure that the pointer has the same name, both in the declaration and when you utilize the pointer. As you can see in my code above, there is an instance of AboutViewController named controller, which is then later referenced as controller when you push the view controller.